# "Cannot resolve class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" even after adding dependencies in gradle

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, drawerlayout

I keep getting the `Cannot resolve class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` error even after adding both the DrawerLayout `androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1` and Material `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` implementations in my build.gradle file.

I have tried adding other implementations, such as `com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0` and `com.android.support:design:25.0.0`, but the error remains and the app won't start.

Any idea on how to fix this?

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.ktu.birthdaycalendar"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"
    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    //lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"

    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
    /*implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:25.0.0"

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"
    //implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0' */
}
```

Comment: Check your Import at java class it Should be

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've imported the wrong version of DrawerLayout.  android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

It should be import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout

Answer (score 3):

Check the class [mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) between the support libraries and androidx libraries:

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ->   androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
```

Use in your layout and in your code [**`androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout).